# Setting imageView by path in Kotlin on Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

This is my code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val imageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
        val uri = Uri.parse("/sdcard/DCIM/88175355_180966049994939_8082373163893129216_n.jpg")
        imageView.setImageURI(uri)
    }
}
```

When run in mobile or AVD `imageView` is blank

Comment: API 26 AndroidX libary

Comment: You do not have access to arbitrary locations on removable storage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do that:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

       val imgFile: File = new  File("/sdcard/DCIM/88175355_180966049994939_8082373163893129216_n.jpg");

        if(imgFile.exists()){

            val myBitmap: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

            val myImage: Image = findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

            myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        }
    }
}
```

And include this permission in the manifest file:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`